# Conversión de tipos de las variables al aplicar una función que convierte valores NA a 0

Tags: r

Al aplicar esta función a un data.frame

```
> reemplazar.na=function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)}
> data.frame.2019 <- data.frame(sapply(data.frame.2019,reemplazar.na))
```

Cambian los tipos de las variables, incluso renombra aquellas variables cuyos nombres son números.
¿Hay alguna alternativa?, lo que he pretendido es convertir aquellos valores ausentes en 0. Para mejorar
la presentación de los datos en formato tabla y poder operar con las columnas.

```
> data.frame.2019 <- spread (data = data.frame.2019, key = cdcta, value = importe)
> str(data.frame.2019)

'data.frame':   62 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ id       : int  652 841 891 933 1168 1478 1766 1997 2306 2333 ...
 $ codbdgel : chr  "04013AA000" "11004AA000" "11012AA000" "11020AA000" ...
 $ municipio: chr  "Almería" "Algeciras" "Cádiz" "Jerez de la Frontera" ...
 $ poblacion: int  198533 121957 116027 212749 325701 232462 143663 112999 574654 143386 ...
 $ 1        : num  5352886 2281244 6087839 6550608 12310977 ...
 $ 2        : num  9749398 5915609 5846830 12379326 18583202 ...
 $ 3        : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ 4        : num  476886 350927 5417820 4588320 4266426 ...
 $ 6        : num  223514 NA 91002 80383 367370 ...
 $ 7        : num  NA NA NA NA 1963771 ...
 $ 8        : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

> reemplazar.na=function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)}
> data.frame.2019 <- data.frame(sapply(data.frame.2019,reemplazar.na))

> str(data.frame.2019)

'data.frame':   62 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ id       : chr  "652" "841" "891" "933" ...
 $ codbdgel : chr  "04013AA000" "11004AA000" "11012AA000" "11020AA000" ...
 $ municipio: chr  "Almería" "Algeciras" "Cádiz" "Jerez de la Frontera" ...
 $ poblacion: chr  "198533" "121957" "116027" "212749" ...
 $ X1       : chr  "5352886.35" "2281244.14" "6087838.89" "6550607.93" ...
 $ X2       : chr  "9749398.02" "5915609.14" "5846829.81" "12379326.16" ...
 $ X3       : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ X4       : chr  "476885.53" "350926.75" "5417819.73" "4588319.88" ...
 $ X6       : chr  "223514.18" "0" "91002.2" "80383.29" ...
 $ X7       : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ X8       : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son dos problemas relacionados:

1. Algunos de tus nombres de columna son expresiones literales de números (`1`, `2`). Eso es problemático porque los números son símbolos reservados en `R`. Además para buscar una columna podemos usar un nombre o el número de índice `(1:ncol(df))`. Si usamos números como nombres se introduce una ambigüedad entre estas dos formas de indizar. Cuando aplicas `sapply()` en el data.frame este "sanitiza" los nombres de columna y les agrega una `X`. Prueba `data.frame(1 = 5)` y `data.frame(x1 = 5)`. En el primer caso tienes un error, en el segundo no.
2. `sapply()` "intenta adivinar"(*) la estructura de datos del output y en este caso arma una matriz. Las matrices son de la familia de los vectores y admiten solamente un tipo de datos. Si se encuentran con algún dato del tipo character van a pasar todos los demás datos a character. Siempre da problemas usar `sapply()` directamente sobre un data.frame. Es mejor evitarlo.

## Solución para 1

Cambiar los nombres. Agregarles algún caracter como prefijo conociendo de antemano los números de índice de las columnas a las que les quiero cambiar el nombre.

```
colnames(data.frame.2019)[5:11] <-paste0("prefijo", colnames(data.frame.2019)[5:11])
```

Alternativamente algo como `janitor::clean_names()` que soluciona este y otros problemas con los nombres de un data.frame.

## Solución para 2

Con `R` base lo que se me ocurre es un poco complicado, quizás haya una manera más fácil.

```
data.frame.2019[sapply(data.frame.2019, is.numeric)] <-  lapply(data.frame.2019[sapply(data.frame.2019, is.numeric)], reemplazar.na)
```

Los que hace es definir primero el subconjunto de las variables que son numéricas. Para eso dentro de `df[]` uso `sapply(df, is.numeric)`. En ese caso es seguro usar `sapply()` porque dados los datos y la función siempre va a regresar un vector lógico. Del lado derecho del símbolo `<-` uso `lapply()`, que pasa la función `reemplazar.na` y regresa una lista como output. Como lo asingo a un subconjunto de `df` entonces automáticamente lo coerciona a data.frame, en lugar de regresar una lista.

Con `mutate_if` de la librería dplyr/tidyverse es bastante más fácil.

```
data.frame.2019 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, reemplazar.na)
```

Hay otra forma de hacerlo que es la que sugieren los desarrolladores de la librería:

```
data.frame.2019 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), reemplazar.na))
```

A mí se me hace más complicada. Se supone que `mutate_if` va a seguir existiendo en las versiones futuras de `dplyr()`, así que sería seguro usarla.

(*) Estrictamente aplica unas reglas de coerción bastante complicadas que dan resultados diferentes dependiendo de input y la función. Para datos aparentemente parecidos puede salir una lista, una matriz o un vector.

Answer (score 2):

Los problemas:

#### 1. Transformación de todas las variables a `character`

Esto es una consecuencia del uso de [`sapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply), puedes consultarlo en la ayuda, la salida de esta función es un vector o una matriz, por consiguiente, el resultado es que todos los valores deben ser del mismo tipo, y el único tipo posible que sea consistente con los datos de origen, en este caso, es el `character`

#### 2. Cambio de nombres de variables

[`data.frame()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/data.frame) por defecto, normaliza los nombres de las variables que no son sintácticamente válidos, puedes eventualmente modificar esto con el parámetro `checknames = FALSE`.

#### Solución:

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(data.frame.2019, reemplazar.na))
```

---

Con `lapply` aplicamos la función a cada columna, y, algo importante, al ser el retorno una lista, mantenemos el tipo de dato. Luego simplemente invocamos `cbind.data.frame()` con cada elemento de la lista para terminar obteniendo nuevamente un `data.frame` consistente con los datos originales.